# How can I merge objects in Sverchok and Animation Nodes?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, animation-nodes, sverchok

I would like to know how I can merge objects into single object in Sverchok and Animation Nodes. I do not want to merge them physically with Ctrl-J, I just want the merging to be dyanmic if you will.  So if I update one of the merge objects , the final merged object would update with the new shape changes basically.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible. First we need to put all objects inside a collection.

**Using Animation Nodes**

In Animation nodes we can use collection info node to get all objects, then convert them into mesh list using `Mesh Input` node(Mesh Input node don't have vectorized input so we need loop). finally merge it using `Join Mesh List` node.
[image]

**Using Sverchok**

In sverchok we only need these 3 nodes, Our new connected object is Alpha.0000
[image]

Comment: how about non-collection ways? Is it possible?

Comment: @yarun can You can create object list instead of collection info node.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it.

Comment: So hitting one issue with this. No materials of the original meshes are in the final merged mesh it seems whether they are individual objects with single materials or objects with multiple materials. Do you know if it is also possible to transfer the materials toi the final mesh in SV or AN?